# Using getProject() with Gradle Configuration Cache

Tags: gradle, gradle-task, gradle-configuration-cache

Gradle documentation states that using the `getProject()` method in the `@TaskAction` method of a `Task` class should not be used if you want compatibility with Gradle Configuration Cache. The question I have is that, suppose you have something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractMyTask extends DefaultTask {
    @Internal
    protected abstract DirectoryProperty getRootDirectory();
    
    protected AbstractMyTask() {
        getRootDirectory().convention(getProject().getRootProject().getLayout().getProjectDirectory());
    }
}
```

The general intent of the code snippet is to have a `Directory` property representing the root project directory (ie. a safe replacement for `getProject().getRootDir()`), and it seems like the `getProject()` call in the constructor would be okay. I'd like some sober second thought on whether that is the case.